# Can someone explain why the below code prints -1

Tags: c, int, 32-bit

can someone explain why the below code outputs `-1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() 
{

int number = 4294967295; /* the maximum integer
that can be represented in 4 bytes (2 ^ 32 -1) */

printf("Maximun Number: %d\n", number); // why this output is strange it prints "-1". outputs: Maximum Number: -1 

printf("sizeof integer: %dbytes", sizeof(int)); // outputs: sizeof integer: 4bytes 

}
```

As you see i have stored the maximum integer( `2 ^ 32 -1` ) that can be stored in `4bytes` in an `int` variable in `C` but i have no idea why this outputs `-1` this is so strange. is this `undefined behavior`.
**is this mentioned somewhere in the [C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html) which i can read if you provide me any link** any explanation is really appreciated about this

Comment: `int` is a signed type. What you claim as the "maximum integer" is ~ the total number of possible numbers that can be stored in `int`, but the actual highest integer possible is actually about half because of the negative half of the possible numbers.

Comment: thank you very much so in the above code its an integer overflow right ?

Comment: As @Chris said, its being implicitly converted to a `long unsigned int` containing all `1` bits. When you try to print it as an `int` two's complement says all `1` bits is `-1` in decimal.

Answer (score 4):

`4294967295` is `2 ^ 32 - 1`, yet the positive range of signed int is `2 ^ 31 - 1`. Assigning a value larger than this is implementation definied (cf. [signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3) in the linked c standard draft):

> (3) Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
> in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
> implementation-defined signal is raised.

One implementation defined behaviour can be to treat the complete 32 bits as a two's complement value. This would yield `-1` then.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the variable `number` is less than `2 ^ 32 - 1`, however `int` types in C are signed integers, meaning the max value is 2147483647, not 4294967296.

The compiler is implicitly converting your `long` number into a signed integer, which changes it to -1

Answer (score 1):

Actually the range for an integer is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Therefore you are generating an overflow. If you print

```
printf("Maximun Number: %ld \n", number); 
//where %ld is a signed and %lu is an unsigned long
```

You will actually get the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `INT_MAX` (and `#include <limits.h>`) instead of you will notice that the maximum positive integer will be `2147483647`.
This is because one bit is used to know the sign of your integer.
Thus the maximum possible number is `2 ^ 31 -1`.